# Get percentage of line bar chartjs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

[image]

React ChartJS.
How can I make a chart like this? I have normal type Line bar but I want to get the percentage too.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to update the percentage outside the chart when you hover on the dates ?

Comment: No, on page render he gets the % of each line in chart @RajKumar

Comment: but my query is which date the percentage calculation will consider, or it will update dynamically on hover of  chart lines ?